# Android set permission inside list-view custom apdpater class

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am trying to set permission to make the phone call  inside custom list adapter class extends from BaseAdapter from `getView` method.

But when touching on icon image the application crash

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        final TextView  phoneTxt  = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
        ImageView phoneImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone_icon);
        phoneImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
               int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
               if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST__PHONE_CALL);
               }
               else {
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                 intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneTxt.getText()));
                 context.startActivity(intent);
               }

        }
    });
    }


    return convertView;
}
```

Here is the error log

```
11-13 11:54:05.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9530): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 11:54:05.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9530): Process: com.myapp.myApp, PID: 9530
11-13 11:54:05.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9530): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
11-13 11:54:05.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9530):     at com.myapp.myApp.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter$1.onClick(NavDrawerListAdapter.java:134)
11-13 11:54:05.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9530):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5269)
11-13 11:54:05.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9530):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21556)
11-13 11:54:05.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9530):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
11-13 11:54:05.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9530):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
11-13 11:54:05.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9530):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
11-13 11:54:05.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9530):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
11-13 11:54:05.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9530):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-13 11:54:05.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9530):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
11-13 11:54:05.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9530):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Why this happening, is there any bug in above code?.

Comment: It clearly tells that the context object is not an activity, it is application context. Please change the context object to activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `context` that you're using here:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST__PHONE_CALL)
                                             ^^^^^^^
```

is `ApplicationContext` and not an Activity's context, wherever you're passing the context to your adapter, try passing :

```
YourActivity.this; // in case your list view is in an activity
getActivity(); // in case it's in a fragment
```

and not `getApplicationContext()`, which is possibly what you're doing right now.

Comment: Yes I am passing context using getApplicationContext() and I have defined the adpater class like `public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {.....`. So do I need to pass activity using `this.activity` from mainactivity.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are trying to cast the context to `Activity` but a `Context` is not necessarily the instance of `Activity`. You may have used `getApplicationContext()` or `getApplication()` as the parameter where `Context` is required. Consider using `YourActivity.this` so that it can be casted to `Activity`.

Or you can use my library to request permissions **from any context** easily.

Check the instructions at https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Eg.

```
Permissions.check(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, null,
    new PermissionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onGranted() {
            //do your task.
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

declare global in your activity or fargment

```
private static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 101;
```

make `checkAndRequestPermissions` method and call in your list or before list.

```
public static boolean checkAndRequestPermissions(Context context) {

    int callphonePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);

    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

    if (callphonePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
    }

    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```